# Checked out branch from detached head, tried to push getting

Tags: git, heroku

I did

```
git checkout someoldhash
git checkout -b rollback_branch
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:myapp.git
git push heroku rollback_branch:master --force

fetching repository, done.
error: src refspec rollback_branch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myapp.git'
```

But I can do

```
git push github someoldhash
```

and it works fine.

How do I rollback my branch to Heroku?

Comment: Did you try git push --force heroku HEAD:master instead?

Comment: I'll try that, can you explain the difference?

Comment: Hey, that works.. what's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work:

```
git push --force heroku HEAD:master
```

That will push the commit referenced by HEAD, without having to check for a branch name.